# Python query SQLite map values to column names

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite, object

I am creating a python script to query a SQLite DB file. I have connected to the SQLite db file and ran the SELECT query to retrieve data.

The issue is that the output is missing the column names.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
import json

con = lite.connect('example.db')

with con:

        con.row_factory = lite.Row

        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Devices")

        rows = cur.fetchall()

        rowarray_list = []
        for row in rows:
                t = (row['id'], row['name'], row['type'])
                rowarray_list.append(t)

        j = json.dumps(rowarray_list)
        rowarrays_file = 'rowarrays.js'
        f = open(rowarrays_file,'w')
        print (f, j)
```

Here is the output of the script.

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='rowarrays.js' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> [[1, "example1", "Computer"], [2, "example2", "Server"], [3, "example3", "Server"]
```

Below is the output required.

```
{"records":[{"id": "1", "name": "example1", "type": "Computer"}, {"id": "2", "name": "example2", "type": "Server"}, {"id": "3", "name": "example3", "type": "Server"}]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're already using `sqlite3.Row` objects, you're probably aware that they have a `keys()` method, which returns a list of column names. Use that. Try modifying this part of your code:

```
rowarray_list = []
for row in rows:
    d = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))   # a dict with column names as keys
    rowarray_list.append(d)
```

Comment: This method works like a charm, if you need JSON, just use json.dumps()

Answer (score 1):

1. You are printing the file object `f`
2. All you want to do is wrap rowarray_list in a dict: `j = json.dumps({"records": rowarray_list})`

Comment: The issue is that the column names are not included in the output.  I need to match the column name to each value.

Current output:

[1, "example1", "Computer"]

Required output:

{"id": "1", "name": "example1", "type": "Computer"}